# Apache Nutch 2.3.1 remote command failed

Tags: java, hadoop, nutch

I have complete setup of nutch  with hadoop and hbase. If I run a job via command line (terminal) if works successfully. But When I want to run same command via nutch wepapp server following exception occured.

```
2016-09-07 12:25:31,800 ERROR impl.RemoteCommandExecutor - Remote command failed
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
    at org.apache.nutch.webui.client.impl.RemoteCommandExecutor.executeRemoteJob(RemoteCommandExecutor.java:61)
    at org.apache.nutch.webui.client.impl.CrawlingCycle.executeCrawlCycle(CrawlingCycle.java:58)
    at org.apache.nutch.webui.service.impl.CrawlServiceImpl.startCrawl(CrawlServiceImpl.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-09-07 12:25:31,850 INFO  impl.CrawlingCycle - Executed remote command data: INJECT status: FAILED
```

I have started tow services for app server i.e. `nutchserver` and `webapp`. I have run these services in both user mode and root user. but same result.

Answer (score 2):

It's the timeout exception in execute job in **RemoteCommandExecuter**.java

Try increasing the maximum timeout to wait to get result. It waits for at most the given time for the computation to complete, and then retrieves the result.

```
private static final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_SEC = 60;

    public JobInfo executeRemoteJob(RemoteCommand command) {
        try {
          String jobId = client.executeJob(command.getJobConfig());
          Future<JobInfo> chekerFuture = executor
              .submit(new JobStateChecker(jobId));
          return chekerFuture.get(getTimeout(command), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          log.error("Remote command failed", e);
          JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo();
          jobInfo.setState(State.FAILED);
          jobInfo.setMsg(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
          return jobInfo;
        }
      }

    private long getTimeout(RemoteCommand command) {
        if (command.getTimeout() == null) {
          return DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_SEC * DateTimeConstants.MILLIS_PER_SECOND;
        }
        return command.getTimeout().getMillis();
      }
```

Change `DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_SEC` to a higher value.